# Ensure that web service handles exceptions and always returns a valid response

Tags: java, web-services, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

I am developing a web service, no matter what, the response should always be valid, and I mean valid as in a valid format.

That means that if the web service is expected to return an XML matching a particular XSD schema, it should ALWAYS return a valid XML document, no matter what.

The only approach that I have so far is to do something like this (at controller level)

```
String xmlResponse = this.loadDefaultXML();
try {
     xmlResponse = this.myCoolService.myCoolMethod();
} catch (Throwable t) {
     xmlResponse = this.loadDefaultXML(String errorMessage)
} finally {
     return xmlResponse
}
```

Where of course `lpoadDefaultXML()` will load an xml document like:

```
<?xml>
<result>Ouch, there was a problem</result>
```

And `loadDefaultXML(String errorMessage)` will do

```
<?xml>
<result>WHATEVER errorMessage contains</result>
```

Of course the service level takes cares of the normal exceptions, still, I feel that catching `Throwable` and using the `try-catch-finally` is the only way to ensure that no matter what, I will be in control so I can return always an XML.

Any better ideas or suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

I am using Spring MVC 3.2 and JAXB for the marshalling/unmarshalling of xml.
This does use SOAP, also I am not using wsdl for this.

Comment: Yours is a good way, but the best, I believe, is to use yours framework's capabilities. Which one is it? Some will allow you to create an exception mapper class that treats `Throwable` (converts them into a XML message). Others will only alow you to catch "business exceptions" (that is, they won't allow you to treat  `Throwable` or `Exception`), in this case, yours is the only way.

Comment: Is this a SOAP service, or something different?

Comment: Is not SOAP, just simple xml request/responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Spring MVC**, when an exception is thrown during the handling of the request, the `DispatcherServlet` will consult the configured `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver`s to handle the thrown exception. The resolver can then **translate** the exception to a **view** to show the user.

To use it, in short, you can either:

- Implement the `HandlerExceptionResolver` interface, which is only a matter of implementing the `resolveException(Exception, Handler)` method and returning a `ModelAndView`.

Or, what I prefer:

- You use the `@ExceptionHandler` method annotation within a controller to specify which method is invoked when an exception of a specific type is thrown during the execution of controller methods. For example:

  ```
  @Controller
  public class PersonController {

      @RequestMapping("person/{id}")
      @ResponseBody
      public Person getById(@PathVariable String id) {
          if ("007".equals(id)) {
              throw new RuntimeException("007 is a secret agent.");
          }
          return personService.getById(id);
      }

      @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class) // this can be an array
      @ResponseBody
      public String handleRuntimeException(RuntimeException ex,
                                           HttpServletRequest request) {
          return "Oops! Something bad happened: "+ex.getMessage();
      }
  }
  ```

Find more info at [Web MVC framework - Handling Exceptions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch15s09.html).